# Migration Framework that converts an existing System to SaaS Model

Tags: migration, cloud, saas, multi-tenant

I have already a Java application, my purpose is to migrate it to a SaaS Model without  rebuilding it from scratch.

Comment: You will not get a single tool to make this change. Understand what is saas and make design and deployment changes. Answers to these questions will help. Where is your application hosted? Do you have different deployments for different consumers? Why is it not saas today?

Comment: My app is based on JEE with extJs deployed on liferay portal for authentication (integration with LDAP) and pages management and many other features.it's deployed in both servers Tomcat 7 and Jboss 5.1.it uses spring for dao injections.the app is in fact a correspondence tool, actually it's used in many municipalities and universities. My plan is to change them SaaS to give more possibilities to the clients(cost,resources..)

Comment: But if make the changes by myself,how can i distinguish what's the best  suitable framework. for example the authentication thing.In fact should i get rid of Liferay Portal?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should read up what SaaS means. SaaS is a licensing/business model.

In short: instead of selling the software, you host it yourself, and sell the ability to use your software, not the software itself. SaaS is language, technology agnostic.

Comment: thanks for responding, and i know what saas means, and i didn't get the question from nothing, i did a research before posting. http://www.aicit.org/AISS/ppl/AISS2348PPL.pdf

Comment: They talk about architecture in the paper you linked. There are no tools that can conjure up new architecture. That's what humans are for.

Comment: Ok is there there a framework that allows doing that?

Comment: this is an example http://www.saas-tenant.com/saas-multi-tenant-architecture.html

Comment: I can add another yet framework called techcello.com, but the truth is these frameworks follow architectural multi-tenancy and not Multi Instance or VM based Multi-Tenancy which might be the option you are looking for i.e No Code Change required.

Comment: the problem with me is that i could not figure out how these frameworks could achieve such changes. in which layers exactly, as u said no code changing but am i supposed to change my columns in db or this is done automatic when i deploy my app.